# Why isn't a semicolon in command substitution output treated identical to one in the original code?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, cd, command-substitution

In my understanding of command substitution this should work, but it doesn't, can you explain me why and how to do something like this.

---

Why does this work:

```
cd ..; echo 123            # output is "123", after changing directories
```

...when this doesn't:

```
cd $(echo "..; echo 123")  # error message is "cd: too many arguments"
```

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is closely related to this question, insofar as both questions stem from the same misunderstanding.

Comment: Just as an intuitive idea of why things work the way they do, though: if you have a string `s='Could not run: echo >/etc/passwd'`, you wouldn't want the command `echo $s` to overwrite `/etc/passwd`, right? (Though `echo $s` [has other bugs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo); it should be `echo "$s"` or, even better, `printf '%s\n' "$s"` to be correct with arbitrary data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command substitution results (like expansion of variables) do not go through all parsing phases; they *only* go through word-splitting[1] and glob expansion[2], and even those happen only when the expansion itself is unquoted.

That means that your result is identical to:

```
cd "..;" "echo" "123"
```

...the semicolon is treated as *literal text* to be passed to the `cd` command, not shell syntax.

**This is a feature, not a bug: If command substitution results were parsed as syntax, writing secure shell scripts handling untrusted data would be basically impossible.**

---

<sub>[1] dividing the results into "words" on characters in `IFS` -- or, by default, whitespace.</sub>
<sub>[2] looking at whether each resulting word can be treated as a filename-matching pattern, and, if so, matching them against the local filesystem.</sub>